# C# AES encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, .net, aes, compact-framework, rijndael

I'm encrypting a string in .Net C#, sending it over using HttpRequest and decrypting it in .Net CF 3.5. Encrypting goes ok, but I get an error when decrypting the string.

Encrypting code:

```
   public string Encrypt(string s)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            //myRijndael.GenerateKey();
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            myRijndael.KeySize = 256;
            myRijndael.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keystring);
            //myRijndael.GenerateIV();
            myRijndael.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IVstring);
            encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(s, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
            string x = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);
    }

private byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
    byte[] encrypted;
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

Decrypting code in CF 3.5:

```
public string Decrypt(string toDecrypt)
{
    byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keystring);
    byte[] keyIV = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IVstring);
    byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt);
    RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
    rDel.Key = keyArray;
    rDel.KeySize = 256;
    rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
}
```

The line **byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);** throws error : **base {System.SystemException} = {"Length of the data to decrypt is invalid."}**

I tried playing around with Padding etc, but to no avail. Thanks for your input.

**EDIT**
As suggested, I tried to use CryptoStream, but to no avail.

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

    string plaintext = null;
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        rijAlg.KeySize = 256;
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

Now I get error:
**base {System.ArgumentException} = {"Value can not be null.\r\nParameter name: inputBuffer"}** at line **plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();**

Comment: Why aren't you using a CryptoStream to decrypt? You're also doing `encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()` before the `csEncrypt` is disposed (although it doesn't matter in practice, as StreamWriter will dispose `csEncrypt` when it's disposed)

Comment: Use a 'CyrptoStream' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I also tried to use CryptoStream, but I still get an error

Comment: @user9671207 it will be a different error, and you will be one step closer to your working solution. You *need* that CryptoStream when decrypting: put it in, then try and solve any errors which result.

Comment: Yes, I did, but I get an error which is apparently a known Microsoft bug. I'm unable to find a work around though (I edited my original post with the CryptoStream function)

Comment: If you do want to avoid CryptoStream, you will need to call TransformBlock *and* TransformFinalBlock, in the appropriate sequence, with the correct parameters.

Comment: You are using UTF8 in one, ASCII in another. Use Base64 on both.